# Merge two UIImages into one

Tags: image, swift

I have merge two images into one. I already implemented it with some help from the internet but it takes around 2,5s. I'm testing on the simulator so let's take it as a reference.

I currently use `UIGraphicsBeingImageContext`. Is there any faster way to achieve it?

```
extension UIImage {
    func overlayWith(image: UIImage, posX: CGFloat, posY: CGFloat, topImageSize: CGSize,
                     combinedImage: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let newWidth = self.size.width < posX + image.size.width ? posX + image.size.width : self.size.width
            let newHeight = self.size.height < posY + image.size.height ? posY + image.size.height : self.size.height
            let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size))
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY), size: topImageSize))
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                combinedImage(newImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the images you are using?

Comment: @Carpsen90 the base image is iPhone image so it is around 3000x4000 and the top image is smaller ~1000x500. I implemented downsampling from WWDC 2018 session 219 (Image and graphics best practices) but it only shrinks down a photo. I tested it on iPhone 7 and it took me ~0,25s so it is almost instantaneous but maybe there are some tricks to speed up this process?

Comment: And btw when I'm combining two photos I get a peak of memory use of about ~170 MB on iPhone 7.

Comment: I've found that this code is almost twice as fast if `topImageSize` has the same with/height ratio as the size of `image`. Needed clarification: Could these images have some transparency, could the alpha channel be different from 1.0?

Comment: @Carpsen90 yep, the top image is .png with transparent background but the base image is not - it is just image taken with iPhone camera

Comment: The peak in memory is due to image decoding: `/*RGBA*/ 4 * (/*base*/ 3000*4000 + /*overlay*/ 1000*500 + /*newImage*/ 3000*4000)` which is almost `93.47`Mbytes

Comment: @Carpsen90 yep, I know. So there is no way to optimize it without losing the quality?

Comment: If speed is paramount, it seems that downsampling is the best way, but I'll keep looking. (Some pointers can be found [here](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2018/416n2fmzz0fz88f/416/416_ios_memory_deep_dive.pdf?dl=1))

Answer (score 1):

On a simulator with the original code, it takes about `1.52s` on my machine.

Since the base image won't get resized (`self.size` is passed in `self.draw(in:)`), and its alpha channel is always `1`, I could gain at least `200ms` by using the following :

```
self.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .copy, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: thanks, cool trick. I managed to drop from `1.13`s to `1.07`s or even `0.98` on the simulator. Not a major improvement but a welcome one.